# Filter queryset with reverse relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

If I have two models

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name="children")
    status = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I can get the latest ModelB object with `ModelA.objects.children.latest('date')` but can I also filter my ModelA queryset against fields in the latest ModelB object? I mean something like

```
ModelA.objects.filter(ModelA.objects.children.latest('date')['status']=1)
```

or

```
ModelA.objects.filter(latest_children__status=1)
```

I know this code wont work but I hope it illustrates what I want.

Comment: are you trying to get the `ModelB` object that is mapped to the latest `ModelA` object?

Comment: I want those ModelA objects having the latest ModelB children objects with status=1. If ModelA is Order and ModelB is Status, I will use it to get those Orders whose current_state/latest_state status is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
ModelA.objects.filter(children__status=1).latest('children__date')
```

Filter the objects first then get latest.

Comment: But I don't want to return the latest object. I want a queryset consisting of ModelA objects having their latest children object's status equal 1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to work, but give it a try.

```
ModelA.objects.filter(children__status=1)\
    .annotate(last_date=Max('children__date'))\
    .filter(children__date=F('last_date'))
```